# Convert nested observables to single observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to write an observable helper function that merges nested sequences into one sequence.  In other words, the signature looks something like this:

```
public IObservable<string> CreateNested(
    Func<IObservable<string>> createOuter, 
    Func<string, IObservable<string>> createInner);
```

One detail is that these sequences wrap service calls, so each sequence will have at most one item.

So my first attempt works, sort of.  But it looks needlessly verbose to me, and also, the use of `Wait` breaks the observable pattern, because errors from either sequence will throw an exception, rather than being propagated back to the returned sequence:

```
public IObservable<string> CreateNested(Func<IObservable<string>> createOuter, Func<string, IObservable<string>> createInner)
{
    return Observable.StartAsync(() =>
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            string outerResult = createOuter().Wait();
            var inner = createInner(outerResult);
            return inner.Wait();
        });
    });
}
```

My second attempt is a bit better, but still makes use of a `Wait`.

```
public IObservable<string> CreateNested(Func<IObservable<string>> createOuter, Func<string, IObservable<string>> createInner)
    return createOuter().FirstOrDefaultAsync()
        .Select(result => createInner(result).Wait());
}
```

If I replace "Wait" above with another "FirstOrDefaultAsync()", then I get `IObservable<IObservable<string>>`.  Is there a correct way to "merge" these two sequences?

---

**Edit** For completeness, my test is below (expected output is "hello world").

```
public class Tester
{
    public void Test()
    {
        CreateNested(CreateOuter, CreateInner).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
    }

    private IObservable<string> CreateOuter()
    {
        return Observable.Create<string>(observer =>
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                observer.OnNext("hello");
                observer.OnCompleted();
            });
            return new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("Outer subscriber released"); });
        });
    }

    private IObservable<string> CreateInner(string key)
    {
        return Observable.Create<string>(observer =>
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                observer.OnNext(key + " world");
                observer.OnCompleted();
            });
            return new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("Inner subscriber released"); });
        });
    }

    private IObservable<string> CreateNested(Func<IObservable<string>> createOuter, Func<string, IObservable<string>> createInner)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try SelectMany?

Comment: @phoog ha ... you rock, Sir.  Go ahead and post as an answer, if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently all you need is to replace Select with SelectMany.

If you're interested in monads, note that SelectMany is the monadic "bind" function, which allows function composition -- exactly what you're trying to achieve here.